# Regular Value Theorem Using Implicit Function Theorem in Calculus.

Tags: multivariable-calculus

I want to prove the following:

> > **THEOREM.** (Regular Value Theorem.) Let $f:\mathbf R^n\to\mathbf R^m$ be a smooth function and $\mathbf a\in\mathbf R^n$ be a regular point of $f$.
> >     Let $f(\mathbf a)=\mathbf 0$ and $\text{rank }Df(\mathbf a)=r$.
> >     Let $R$ be the set of all the regular points of $f$.
> >     Then $R\cap f^{-1}(\mathbf 0)$ is an $(n-r)$-manifold (without boundary) in $\mathbf R^n$.

I can prove the above using the Rank Theorem but I was wondering if this can be proved using the Implicit Function Theorem. In fact, the instructor of my Differential Equations course hinted that this can be done.

**THEOREM** (Implicit Function Theorem.) Let $f:\mathbf R^{m+n}\to \mathbf R^n$ be a smooth function.
Interpret $f$ in the form $f(\mathbf x,\mathbf y)$ for $\mathbf x\in\mathbf R^m$ and $\mathbf y\in \mathbf R^n$.
Let $(\mathbf a,\mathbf b)\in\mathbf R^{m+n}$ be such that $f(\mathbf a,\mathbf b)=\mathbf 0$ and $\det\displaystyle\frac{\partial f}{\partial \mathbf y}\neq 0$.
Then there exists a neighborhood $U$ of $\mathbf a$ in $\mathbf R^m$, and a unique continuous function $g:U\to \mathbf R^n$ such that $g(\mathbf a)=\mathbf b$ and $f(\mathbf x,g(\mathbf x))=\mathbf 0$ for all $\mathbf x\in U$.
Further, the function $g$ is a smooth function.

---

The definitions I am using are

**DEFINITION.** Let $f:\mathbf R^n\to\mathbf R^m$ be a smooth function.
A point $\mathbf a\in \mathbf R^n$ is said to be a **regular point** of $f$ if $$\text{rank }Df(\mathbf a)=\max\{\text{rank }Df(\mathbf x):\mathbf x\in\mathbf R^n\}$$

**DEFINITION.** A subset $M$ of $\mathbf R^n$ is said to be a $k$-**manifold** (without boundary) if for each point $\mathbf p\in M$, there is a set $V$ open in $M$ containing $\mathbf p$, an open set $U$ in $\mathbf R^k$, and a bijective map $\alpha:U\to V$ satisfying:

1. $\alpha^{-1}:V\to U$ is continuous.
2. $D\alpha(\mathbf x)$ has rank $k$ for each $\mathbf x\in U$.

   ---

**Attempt:** Consider the statement of the Regular Value Theorem as given above and assume for a special case that $m=r$. Write $M=R\cap f^{-1}(\mathbf 0)$.
Then using the Implicit Function Theorem, there exists a neighborhood $U$ of $\mathbf a$ in $\mathbf R^m$, and a continuous function $g:U\to\mathbf R^n$ such that $f(\mathbf x,g(\mathbf x))=\mathbf 0$ for all $\mathbf x\in U$.
Now define the function $\alpha:U\to \mathbf R^n$ as $\alpha(\mathbf x)=(x,g(\mathbf x))$. The only trouble now is to show that $\alpha(U)$ is open in $M$.
Can anybody see how to do that? Also, can anybody suggest an approach when $m>r$?

Thanks.

Comment: Does this blog post help? https://unapologetic.wordpress.com/2011/04/21/regular-and-critical-points/ It's the one I always wind up reading when thinking about this.

Comment: Thank you for the response. I do not want to think about it now. Will read it later sometime.