# Proof that intersection of manifolds is submanifold

Tags: differential-topology, transversality

I need some help with understanding this proof. I have 2 questions:

1. What are those functions $f$,$g$? I mean what is the idea behind them?
2. Why do we consider $f^{-1}(0)$ exactly? Where does this $0$ come from?
   [image]

Comment: You have to look back at the definition of transverse and regular to find out where $f$ and $g$ come from. That's more than we can provide here.

Comment: this f and g cames from the relugar value theorem, see: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/913616/regular-value-theorem-using-implicit-function-theorem-in-calculus

Comment: Do you know the [regular value/preimage theorem](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Preimage_theorem), if not look it up. It is used here as the approach.

Comment: Thank you for replying. But I still don't understand why we consider exactly $0$ here and not any other value.